# React Native - Parse URL to get Query Variable

Tags: react-native, javascriptcore

Looking for a way to parse a URL to get a query variable in React Native received from Linking.

I'm receiving the URL as something like:

url-app-scheme://somePage?someVar=someVal

I'd like to get the someVar value from the URL.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 29):

This should do the trick

```js
var url = "http://example.com?myVar=test&otherVariable=someData&number=123"

var regex = /[?&]([^=#]+)=([^&#]*)/g,
  params = {},
  match;
while (match = regex.exec(url)) {
  params[match[1]] = match[2];
}
console.log(params)
```

Comment: If someone wants explanation then please see this reference, also thanks @Ray, ref=`https://www.jskap.com/blog/React-Native-parse-url-query-params/`

Comment: but this won't work if you pass parameter=your_url_with_character_#_hash, I am passing url as param containing `#`, and it's not working there.

Comment: Can you give a little explanation too?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but using RegExp isn't safe, using [`query-string`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string) would be better.

Answer (score 16):

There is a [URL class in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) which is intended to let you both build and parse URLs robustly, making query parameters easily accessible:

```js
const url = new URL('url-app-scheme://somePage?someVar=someVal');
url.searchParams.get('someVar')
```

Sadly, the implementation of `URL` in React Native is not complete [and has some known bugs](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/24428). Fortunately, there is a solid polyfill library called [react-native-url-polyfill](https://github.com/charpeni/react-native-url-polyfill) which provides an implementation of `URL` that is well behaved and tested - I highly recommend it.

Comment: for me, React Native says "not implemented" when using `new URL(...`

Answer (score 6):

Using query-string its working

```
yarn add  query-string

import queryString from 'query-string';

const parsed = queryString.parseUrl("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?offset=10&limit=10");
console.log(parsed.query.offset) will display 10
```

Answer (score 4):

There are ways of doing this that you can leverage from the JS ecosystem. Try URI.js https://github.com/medialize/URI.js

Answer (score 2):

I have the same requirement the above solution works for me just to add on with the above answer below worked for me as well

```
const regex = /[?&]([^=#]+)=([^&#]*)/g;

let params = {},match;

 while ((match = regex.exec(url))) {
   params[match[1]] = match[2];
 }
console.log('parsed params', params);
```

For **example** if the input is like below

https://example.com/masterplan/user?auth_token=175032c6210c32833ac70447c3f049cf9126343af9a9399373ff58e87d06479e845f35b93bc6c234ba37a9dec9&userId=1256345&userType=78

**Output will be like below**

> **{"auth_token":
> "175032c6210c32833ac70447c3f049cf9126343af9a9399373ff58e87d06479e845f35b93bc6c234ba37a9dec9",
> "userId": "1256345", "userType": "95"}**

Answer (score 1):

Try url https://www.npmjs.com/package/url

"This module has utilities for URL resolution and parsing meant to have feature parity with node.js core url module."

The node URL object is available to your app when using the Chrome react-native debugger, but is not available on your iPhone when untethered.

So use this package

```
npm install url
```

Sample code:

```
import url from 'url';

...

let urlObject = url.parse(inUrlString);
let outUrlString = urlObject.protocol + '//' + urlObject.host + '/more/jump?jump_path=' + encodeURIComponent(urlObject.pathname);
```

Comment: Could you please tell me, how can I extract url-params using this module, I seen it's github docs, but could not figure out, for `url="example.com/path/?id=1"`?

Answer (score 0):

```js
url="example.com/path/?id=1"
let urlObject = url.parse(url, true); // second parameter `true` (parse search query)
console.log(urlObject.query['id']); // 1
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -2):

Update: This is not a solution to the above question because it doesn't work unless in debugging mode. I have not deleted this answer however, because I think it points out a note worthy nuance.

JavaScript's very own [URL Web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/URL) is supported in React Native (using version 0.46). You can use to to parse or build any and every part of the url with great ease.

The API is identical to the [WHATWG API of the URL module in Node.js](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_the_whatwg_url_api) This answer should really be more obvious, but its easy to get lost with the number of okay url parsing packages available.

Edit: This works only in the JS debugging mode for some reason, and not otherwise. So this solution doesn't really hold valid, but I'm leaving it here because I'd love to know how to get the same URL module to work with react-native.

Comment: This might be because it is coming from your browser instead of react native. That is too bad :(

Comment: When you turn on "Remote JS Debugging", your code will run in the browser instead of your device. Chrome uses V8 and RN uses JavaScriptCore so you experience differences like this. You can get more information here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/javascript-environment.html

Comment: @AlicanC thanks for clarifying the reason behind this behaviour with your comment.