# getting information from url

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, antd

React beginner here, English is not my mother language so sorry for mistakes. I have url from there I want to get information I will show how I have done other pages(using `antd` form), but now I'm in different page where at the end of my url is `payer=sender`, so if `payer` is `"sender"` then do this. that 'payer=sender' at the end of my url comes by clicking a sender button, then when it is clicked form input should fill accordingly

```js
const senderPays = () => {
    history.push(`/bilInfo/${custId}?${query}&payer=sender`);
  };
```

```html
          <Button onClick={senderPays}>Sender</Button>
```

In previous pages I could get `pickUpName` from url like this :

```
const query = window.location.toString().split("?")[1];

const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(query);

const PickUpName = urlParams.get("pickUpName") || props.customer?.name;
  
<Form.Item
  label="pickUpName"
  name="pickUpName"
  initialValue={PickUpName || ""}
>
  <Input type="string" />
</Form.Item>
```

This is my url: `https://localhost:5001/#/billingInfo/5dc9d690-a549-4baf-868e-a441c6c4ff47?pickUpName=gholam&pickUpContactPerson=&pickUpPhone=8744444&pickUpAddress=gerbytnie&pickUpPostalCode=65230&pickUpPostalRegion=helsnki&deliveryName=shammms&deliveryContactPerson=kalle&deliveryPhone=2658265&deliveryAddress=&deliveryPostalCode=65230&deliveryPostalRegion=&payer=sender`

As you can see end of url is `&payer=sender`
so if `payer` is sender then have these information and if `payer` is receiver then have these information:

this is my code:

```
useEffect(() => {
if (payer === "sender") {
  billingName = PickUpName;
} else if (payer === "receiver") {
  billingName = DeliveryName;
}
```

}, [payer]);

Component

```
<Form.Item
  label="billingName"
  name="billingName"
  initialValue={billingName || ""}
>
  <Input type="string" />
</Form.Item>
```

So I need somehow to get that `billingName` in my forms initialValue, depending who is `payer`.

Comment: Without complete code of this component is very unclear. So, please full code snippet of the component.

Comment: Isnt it simple, if at the end of url is payer=sender then that condiotions inside if and i want to have that data for example billingName in my forms initialValue...

Comment: It is simple, the logic `payer=sender`. But where to apply based on assumption will be time-wasting. So, providing just these components code snippets will save time.

Comment: Please try to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so it's more clear what you may be trying to do. It's unclear why what you were doing on previous pages won't also work on *this* page. Or perhaps you are asking something different. Try clarifying what you want and what isn't working as expected.

Comment: why i wrote what i did on previous page is because that pickUpName which is inside if condition is same as const PickUpName = urlParams.get("pickUpName"), which is in url, so need to use that

Comment: i have two buttons one for sender and one for receiver, so if user clicks 'sender pays' button then at the end of url will appear that 'payer=sender' and then form input will fill accordingly

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native - Parse URL to get Query Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44038180/react-native-parse-url-to-get-query-variable)

Comment: @Masood no, i can get data from url like this : const PickUpName = urlParams.get("pickUpName"), but when user clicks a sender button, at the end of my url appears payer=sender, then i want to give it conditions and according to those conditions fill the form (conditions values are already in url)

Answer (score 0):

#### Use the useForm react hook to manually initialize fields:

Summary:

1. Initialize a form instance using `useForm()`.
2. Pass that `FormInstance` to your `Form`
3. Use `useEffect` hook to dynamically set the value of the `Form.Item` based on the value of `payer`

```
import { Form } from 'antd';


const Demo = () => {
  // Note that `useForm` is a React Hook and will only works in functional components
  const [form] = Form.useForm();

  const payer = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('payer');

  // Manually initialize billingName based on `payer` value 
  useEffect(() => {

    if (payer === "sender") {
      form.setFieldsValue({ billingName: request.pickUpName });
    } else if (payer === "receiver") {
      form.setFieldsValue({ billingName: request.deliveryName });
    }

  }, [payer])

  // Pass the FormInstance `form` to your Form
  return (
      <Form form={form}>
        <Form.Item
          label="billingName"
          name="billingName"
        >
          ...   
       </Form.Item>

      ...
  )
```

Here's some documentation to help you out:

- [Antd: manually setting form field values](https://ant.design/components/form/#components-form-demo-control-hooks)
- [React: useEffect hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

Comment: i'm using typescript getting this Argument of type '(request: CreateCargoOrderRequest) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EffectCallback'.ts(2345)

Comment: Do not assign anything to useEffect. You need to pass a callback as 1st the argument of useEffect. The 2nd argument is a list of parameters that will trigger the callback you present as the 1st argument to run

Comment: At the moment it doesnt recognize request, could you add ’request:CreatCargoOrderRequest’ to it

Comment: Please update your question to include details on what `request` is. Include information regarding where it comes from, and the callee that will be calling that function

Comment: the way you wrote const payer i'm getting null, but i tried this way and got payer:   const query = window.location.toString().split("?")[1];
const payer = new URLSearchParams(query).get("payer");
console.log(query);

Comment: that 'pickUpName ' inside if condition is the one in url already, const query = window.location.toString().split("?")[1];
  const urlParamss = new URLSearchParams(query);                                                                                const PickUpName = urlParamss.get("pickUpName");

Comment: it takes those from url above, you can get rid of request inside if condition, that way it makes it easier to understand

Comment: i have two buttons one for sender and one for receiver, so if user clicks 'sender pays' button then at the end of url will appear that 'payer=sender' and then form input will fill accordingly