# can we pass invitation code in url in react native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-deep-linking

I'm trying to signup User in React Native. There are 2 steps to do it
When I enter the info of user Like (FirstName, LastName, and email), the User got a link in his/her mail.
When the User is clicking on this link, its redirecting to New Signup Page with two more fields Like Password and Address.
I want to send a inviation code to a user through a link.
How can we send invitation code along with app link and how to handle this when user open app??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your query completely but, you would need to use [react-native-branch](https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/react-native) or [react-navigation-linking](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/configuring-links).

Please follow through with the documents to get a roadmap.

Comment: Second link helped me in understanding this
Thanks for your help
Will Comment later If I Stucked again in any Problem

Answer (score 2):

Let's break down the problem into sub-problems.

**1. Deep link and Universal Linking**

Register your app for the deep link with custom  `myapp://path/to/resource` and universal link `https:yourcompany.com/path/to/ressource`.

**Note:** Apple required domain name ownership verification for universal linking.

React Native CLI - https://venturedevs.com/en/blog/implementing-deep-linking-react-native-apps/

Expo - https://docs.expo.dev/guides/linking/

**2. Sending verification code to email.**

Logic to send email should be handled on the backend or using third-party mail services like sendGrid.

Assume that the user receives an email with a verification link like `https://auth.yoursecret-server.com/myapp?authCode=35467809876`

**3. Deep link to the code verification screen**

React Navigation has first-class support for deep linking, I recommend it for handling screen-based deep linking. Consult their documentation for further.
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/deep-linking

Answer (score 0):

In such case what we have done is we have added invitation code in custom URL like below

```
testapp://singup/invite/abc123456
```

and completed [android](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/deep-linking/#android) and [ios](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/deep-linking/#ios) native setups

next in app

```js
import { Linking } from "react-native"


  React.useEffect(() => {
    Linking.addEventListener("url", _handleDeepLinkURL)
    return () => {
      Linking.removeEventListener("url", _handleDeepLinkURL)
    }
  }, [])

  const _handleDeepLinkURL= async ({ url }) => {
   let inviteCode = parseUrlForCode(url)
   let validation = await api.validate(inviteCode,userEmail)
  }
```

Comment: Brother
How can i send invitation code along with link
Now I'm sending link like this
demo://SignUp to open SignUp Page
demo://ForgotPassword to open Forgot Password Page directly

Comment: you can use query params demo://SignUp?inviteCode=123 and parse the url using any of the method they have mentioned
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44038180/react-native-parse-url-to-get-query-variable/48217789

Comment: Done it with the help of Following Link https://reactnavigation.org/docs/configuring-links/